# Problem with the homepage slider and content images position

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, image, home, position

I'm trying to bring the slider and the related images on right of the page but nothing seems to be working out perfectly. The slider is in perfect position but the image which should be on the right side, next to the slider has moved below it. Also, When you scroll down the page you'll can find only 2 Promotional block images in a row and again the other one has moved down. According to the Demo of the theme, all the images should be in a row.

Let me tell you one thing that I'm an amateur in programming and Magento too, I'm unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone please help me out?

The actual page should look like this as per the demo: https://www.pagayo.com/magento-themes/pt001.html

But my page looks like this: http://www.dirtrades.com

Comment: select valid homepage layout like 1 column in demo.

Comment: You're a genius Mr. Ravi. It worked for me! I owe you a treat. One last question. May I know from where I can change the images of the slider? Actually the link for the images has directories which I couldn't find- <a href="{{store url="#"}}"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/pagayo/pt001/pt001-home-slider3.jpg"}}"/></a> I couldn't find any directory named "wysiwyg". The products I'm going to sell are totally different from what they are being displayed in demo.

Comment: please admin setting to display path hint to easy to find path for template which file use.

Comment: skin\adminhtml\default\default\images\wysiwyg

Comment: You rock @ravipatel. Thanks a ton! You're an angel for the non-programmers and amateurs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select valid layout 1 column for homepage page.

If you can select home page just change hear.

[image]

Comment: I hate bothering you every single time, but I couldn't find the Slider images on the path provided by you- skin\adminhtml\default\default\images\wysiwyg  There was only image named "skin_image.png" I need the folder where the slider images are located.

Comment: I'm sorry. I found it. I just clicked on "Copy image URL" and found out the folder. Thanks anyway :)